# При скачивании и обработки видео с Youtube (pytube и ffmpeg) заполняется вся память ССД

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pytube

столкнулся с крайне серьезной проблемой: При скачивании видео с помощью pytube и его обработке с помощью ffmpeg иногда вся физическая память заполняется до отказа (на сервере установлен ссд на 500+гб, через некоторое время остается просто 0).
На сервере часто скачиваются и обрабатываются видео и эта проблема возникает крайне редко, что просто не дает возможности проследить на каком именно этапе работы это происходит.

Использую библиотеки pytube и бинарник ffmpeg.
Мой код:

```
def download_video(url, info, user_id):
    try:
        path = YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download("archives", max_retries=3)
        os.rename(path, f"archives\\{user_id} video.mp4")

        os.system(f'ffmpeg.exe -i "archives\\{user_id} video.mp4" -vf noise=alls=1:allf=t "archives\\{user_id} video_1.mp4"')
        os.remove(f"archives\\{user_id} video.mp4")
        return "Done"
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        return "Error"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Я до последнего грешил на библиотеку для скачивания видео, но теперь думаю что дело все таки в ffmpeg, где то читал что люди сталкивались с похожими проблемами, но так и не нашел решения или какой либо конкретики по поводу источника бага.

Comment: Чем заполняется?

Comment: сам файл видео раздувается до такого обьема. Чем конкретно - не изучали, т.к. непрерывность работы всего проекта крайне важна и времени на исследования в такой обстановке нет, да и происходит это зачастую ночью

Comment: Убрал работу с ffmpeg в этот же день, оставил только скачивание, итог: Видео весит 500гб)

Comment: Нечего себе видосик)

Comment: ну, стоит ограничение на 5минут и 30 секунд, а как бы в плане веса меня спросить забыли видимо

Comment: нашел таки видео на которых происходит такой атас. Могу сделать вывод, что от самого видео это вообще не зависит. Такое происходит на полном рандоме. Как лечить - даже не подозреваю.

Comment: Наверное придется пересоздать вопрос с новыми пояснениями, да и суть уже другая